# differentiate between single click and double click on Home button in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, appdelegate

I want to handle single click and double click on Home button separately.
I know `applicationWillResignActive:` but it gets call in both conditions.
`applicationDidEnterBackground:` but I want to process data before app goes in background not after.

Is there any way I can recognise *single* and *double* click on home button separately?

Comment: No there isn't another way u need to put your code either in applicationWillResignActive or applicationDidEnterBackground

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. You can only see when your app enters the background (or terminates). You can't see *why*.

Comment: There are two separate app flow I need to handle. So I need to know single click and double click.

Comment: I understand that's what you want but you can't do it. You'll have to find some other flow I'm afraid.

Comment: Ok… I am accepting this answer but need to find out way now!

Answer (score -1):

when application in running
**single click** will call

- applicationwillresigned
- applicationDidEnterBackground

but **double click** will call only

- applicationwillresigned

and will wait for your response.

you can use bool to figure out whether it is double or single click

Comment: **bold** 'single click' when app is being played

these two method will be called
 
applicationwillresigned                                  applicationDidEnterBackground

**bold** 'single click' after that, these method will be called

applicationWillEnterForeground                        applicationDidBecomeActive

but on  **bold** 'double click'

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application { NSLog(@"applicationWillTerminate:")                                    }

will be called

Comment: second time "single click" is click on app

Comment: first few line is the answer of you question @iAsh